# How to send CSV contents to server using android app

Tags: android, csv, server, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to upload CSV file contents to server. I tried following code

```
// CSV file
File sourceFile = new File(path,fileName);

// Https "PUT" Request
URL myurl = new URL(upload_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
con.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3Factory());
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/csv");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
```

But how to add CSV file contents to PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Use a networking library like OkHttp or volley for network requests instead, here is the link to an OkHttp tutorial [here](http://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial/%22here%22)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MultipartRequest` feature of `Volley library` to achieve this. By using multipart , you can upload the files of any extension i.e: pdf/png/ppt/docx etc.